# Initial objects as adjoints

Tags: category-theory

> Viewing functors $1\to\mathcal A$ as objects of $\mathcal A$, a left adjoint to $\mathcal A\to 1$ is exactly an initial object of $\mathcal A$.

Let $Ob(1)=\{\star\}$, let $F:1\to \mathcal A$ be the functor that assigns to the object of $1$ the initial object of $\mathcal A$ and let $G:\mathcal A\to 1$ be the constant functor. The above means at least that there is a bijection $$\mathcal A (F(\star),A)\simeq1(\star,G(A))$$ where $A\in Ob(\mathcal A)$; or, since $F(\star)$ is the initial object in $\mathcal A$, in symbols $F(\star)=I$, and since $G(A)=\star$, there is a bijection $$\mathcal A(I,A)\simeq 1(\star,\star)$$ (and the compositions are identities).

I couldn't figure out how to assign to an arrow $I\to A$ and arrow $\star\to \star$ (or vice versa). How to do that? How to use that $I$ is initial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $1(\star, G(A)) = 1(\star, \star) = \{ \mathrm{id}_{\star} \}$, so:

- If there is a bijection $\mathcal{A}(F(\star), A) \cong 1(\star, G(A))$ for each $A \in \mathcal{A}$, then $\mathcal{A}(F(\star), A)$ has a unique element. This unique element is precisely the morphism ${!}_A : F(\star) \to A$ witnessing that $F(\star)$ is initial.
- Conversely, if $I$ is initial, then $\mathcal{A}(I,A)$ has a unique element ${!}_A : I \to A$, and so there is automatically a bijection $\mathcal{A}(I,A) \cong 1(\star, \star)$ since both of these sets have one element.

Comment: The definition of adjoints is about an isomorphism of the form $\mathscr B(F(A),B)\cong\mathscr A(A,G(B))$. This is an isomorphism in which category? I thought it was an iso in the category of sets, but I just realized that $\mathscr B(F(A),B)$ can fail to be a set.

Comment: Usually when we're using the hom-set definition of adjunctions, we take the categories to be locally small.

Comment: @user634426 It's not quite the category of sets since we want it to be natural in $A$ and $B$. It's the category of functors $\mathscr A^{op}\times\mathscr B\to\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: @DerekElkins I wonder why Leinster himself doesn't specify this, he just silently uses the symbol $\cong$. Apart from that, locally small categories and functors $\mathcal A^{op}\times B\to\mathbf {Set}$ haven't been discussed at this point (but will be discussed in later chapters).

Comment: @user634426: He does, just not in those terms. In Definition 2.1.1 he says 'naturally in $A$ and $B$', and in the paragraph afterwards he defines what that means. And it turns out that this is equivalent to saying that the bijections assemble into a natural isomorphism between functors $\mathcal{A}^{\mathrm{op}} \times \mathcal{B} \to \mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: ...in fact, he hints at this in Remarks 2.1.2(a): "*The naturality axiom might seem ad hoc, but we will see in Chapter 4 that it simply says that two particular functors are naturally isomorphic.*" (And then he says what he means in Remark 4.1.24.)

Comment: But if his $\cong$ means isomorphism in the category of functors $\mathcal A^{op}\times \mathcal B\to\mathbf{Set}$, then $\mathcal B(F(A),B)$ should be an object in this category (i.e. a functor), but it's a class. And in Example 2.1.3 to prove the isomorphism $\cong$ he doesn't find two mutually inverse natural transformations (which are morphisms between functors), rather he is talking about two mutually inverse functions. This last fact makes me think again that he understands $\cong$ as isomorphism in the category of sets... Maybe I will understand what he means after I read Chapter 4.

Comment: @user634426: Right, for fixed objects $A$ and $B$, the symbol $\cong$ means bijection. But when you add 'naturally in $A$ and $B$', it means that these bijections assemble into a natural isomorphism of functors. A natural isomorphism between functors $\mathcal{A}^{\mathrm{op}} \times \mathcal{B} \to \mathbf{Set}$ *is* a family of bijections.

Comment: @CliveNewstead Thanks for the explanation. Then I suppose there is some kind of inaccuracy in Leinser's text. He only defines $\cong$ to mean "isomorphism" in a category (right after Definition 1.1.4), so if here $\cong$ to be understood to be just a bijection (an isomorphism in the category of sets), then he should have specified that and said something about why these are sets (or explicitly stated that this question is postponed until Chapter X).

Comment: @user634426: There is no mistake in his book. Isomorphisms are understood to be in whatever category theory objects are in (sets in this case) and it is conventional in category theory to say things like "the morphism $f_A : F(A) \to G(A)$ is natural in $A$" to mean that the specification of a morphism in a category $\mathcal{D}$ extends to a specification of a natural transformation in a functor category $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}]$. That is what happened here. You'll see similar things in every category theory book. [I think I'll stop here; 
I don't think this discussion is going anywhere.]